# How to remove a vpn interface upon disconnection?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

It used to work before (in Ubuntu 18.04): I connect to a vpn (openconnect) through the GUI (KDE network manager), it creates a new vpn0 interface, and when I disconnect from the vpn, the interface disappears.

Now, however, the vpn0 interface is not removed after disconnection, so now I'm disconnected from the vpn, but still have the vpn0 interface. (To be honest, I can't guarantee it wasn't there since boot up, but I don't think so.) Is it possible to get back the old behaviour?

ETA: When I say the interface is not removed, I mean it appears with `ifconfig`. Running `ifconfig vpn0 down` disables/removes it as I'd like, but when I connect to the vpn it is brought up again and it stays after disconnection.

Comment: After disconnecting, is the interface in "down" state?

Comment: @DanielB I don't think so, see the edited question.

Comment: Try `sudo pkill -SIGINT openconnect`.

Comment: @harrymc What's that supposed to do? I don't want to kill openconnect, I just want the interface to be *automatically* turned off when I disconnect the vpn (just as it is automatically turned on when I connect).